# Callbacking a function with arguments

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have an exercise where I have to give three arguments: function and two numbers.
The function which I give has to be activated (each) after `x` miliseconds for `y` miliseconds.
I wanted to make `helper` like this:

```
function helper(string) {
  console.log("Printing string which was given: " + string)
}
```

but when I do it like this and I try to enable my function `ex1_4(helper("some string"), 500,5000)` I get an error that `Callback must be a function`
What am I doing wrong?

```
function ex1_4(func, x,y) {
    const resFunction = setInterval((func), x)
    const stop = setTimeout(() => {clearInterval(resFunction)}, y)
}
function helper(string) {
    console.log("Printing string which was given: " + string)

}
ex1_4(helper("some string"),500,5000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
helper("some string")
```

Is a function call which returns a value, in your case it is undefined. If you want to make it into a callback, you need to wrap it in a function like so:

```
 () => helper(“some string”)
```

In your code:

```
ex1_4(() => helper("some string"),500,5000)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add  `helper("some string")`, you're actually executing the method, instead of sending the method to `ex1_4`. You should type something like ...

```
ex1_4(helper,500,5000)  // no parenthesis
```

... just like you did with `setInterval((func), x)`.

However, you want to add parameters to `helper`, and in this case, you can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). You should really learn about `bind()`, `call()`, and `apply()`.

```
ex1_4(helper.bind(null, "some string"),500,5000)
```

```js
function ex1_4(func, x,y) {
    const resFunction = setInterval((func), x)
    const stop = setTimeout(() => {clearInterval(resFunction)}, y)
}
function helper(string) {
    console.log("Printing string which was given: " + string)

}

ex1_4(helper.bind(null, "some string"),500,5000)
```